# Intercept when Fields are added to a TFDQuery descendant

Tags: delphi, firedac, delphi-11-alexandria

Is there a way to intercept when Fields are added to a FDQuery descendant ?

I have added a Method (BeautifyDisplayLabels) to set DisplayLabels with a more natural look than their FieldNames (factoryLine5 -> Factory Line 5).

But instead of having to call that method manually I would like for it to be called automatically every time a new persistent field is added to the Query in design time. Which is the method that I should override to intercept fields being added in design time ?.

Thank you.

```
unit MyQuery;

interface

uses System.Classes, FireDAC.Comp.Client;

type TKpQuery = class(TFDQuery)
  private
    function BeautifyFieldName(FieldName: string): string;
  protected
  public
    procedure BeautifyDisplayLabels;
  published
end;

procedure Register;

implementation

uses
  Data.DB,
  System.Types,
  System.SysUtils,
  System.StrUtils,
  System.RegularExpressions;

procedure Register;
begin
  {$IFDEF WIN32}
  RegisterComponents('My Data Access', [TKpQuery]);
  {$ENDIF}
end;
   
procedure TKpQuery.BeautifyDisplayLabels;
var i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to Fields.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if (Fields[i].DisplayLabel.Trim = '') or (Fields[i].DisplayLabel = Fields[i].FieldName) then
      Fields[i].DisplayLabel := BeautifyFieldName(Fields[i].FieldName);
  end;
end;

function TKpQuery.BeautifyFieldName(FieldName: string): string;
var
  Words: TStringDynArray;
  i: integer;
begin
  FieldName := TRegEx.Replace(FieldName, '([a-z])([A-Z])', '$1 $2'); // factoryLine -> factory Line
  FieldName := TRegEx.Replace(FieldName, '([a-z]|[A-Z])(\d)', '$1 $2'); // Line123 -> Line 123
  FieldName := TRegEx.Replace(FieldName, '(\d)([a-z]|[A-Z])', '$1 $2'); // 1428ElmStreet -> 1428 ElmStreet

  Words := FieldName.Split([' ', '.', '_']);
  for i := 0 to Length(Words) - 1 do
    Words[i] := UpperCase(Words[i][1]) + Copy(Words[i], 2, 999);

  Result := String.Join(' ', Words);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Instead of creating a TDataSet descendant, you may consider registering a replacement for TDataSetEditor returning a derived TDSDesignerClass, which overrides DoCreateField. That would even work for other dataset classes.

Comment: Thanks @UweRaabe I've never worked with those editors. It makes sense to do it there, I will look at it. Thank you. PS: The reason to create a Dataset descendant is because my boss wants to also alter some other behaviour, like overriding the DoOnNewRecord to set all the boolean fields to False by default.